# Beautiful Soup install error - Python - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am starting with Python - Selenium and I cannot run the Beautiful Soup Library for Python. I have got installed the Python version 3.8.2 and prepared the version 4.9.0 of Beautiful Soup 4. When I check cmd and ask for this library there is says "Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:...\python38-32\lib\site-packages (4.9.0)". The library is already installed manually by cmd. But the problem is that when I try to use the Beautiful Soup in PyCharm the script is every time ended by following error:

```
'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
```

The function is called by:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Please what I do wrong? Is the incompatible version of Python and Beautiful Soup or the error is somewhere else? I need to webscrape table from website data table but I don´t find another option without use the Beautiful Soup.

Many thanks.

Comment: did you try `pip install -u beautifulsoup4`?

Comment: Are you able to run bs4 from python 3 IDE.Seems like pycharm has python2 Sdk path instead of python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying installing manually in PyCharm:

```
Files > Settings > Projects(to the left)> python interpreter>  click on '+' symbol (to 
   the left) and search for beautifulsoup4 and click on install packages.
```

Also check for the python version that you are using in PyCharm.